# LTspice capacitor only circuit (DC)

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice

I am trying to make a DC circuit simulation to figure out the voltage across 2 capacitors in series, but it won't show me anything remotely reasonable and does not give any voltage across the capacitors.

The circuit is very simple; it's battery/voltage source to c1 to c2 with ground, and every example I have seen more or less uses a resistor, which I do not want in the circuit at all.

I am relatively new to LTspice and I can't for the life of me figure out why this does not give me anything to work with.

Comment: Because the system of equations presented by a voltage source and two series capacitors gives a singular matrix. It's one of the situations where the assumption of zero ESR breaks down.

Comment: but how would i determine the voltage across them in that case? how would i fix this?

Comment: Add some non-idealities so that your circuit represents something physically realizable.

Comment: so, add in resistors between them and then run the sim? would i not need some very low resistances so that they would resemble this in a physical version of the circuit?

Comment: In this case, resistors across them to represent leakage would also be prudent. Unfortunately, leakage resistance is not something you can find on your average capacitor datasheet (it's not usually even linear). Though you can find equivalent series resistance on most capacitor datasheets, at least for electrolytic capacitors (where it can be quite high).

Comment: You can see a video tutorial on LT spice. I'm sure its not so hard to make a circuit in LT spice once you familiarize yourself with circuit elements in it.

Comment: like, i need the individual voltages of c1 and c2 separately, and most of what i have seen is stuff i tried and failed to make work, like setting the starting v to 0 etc.

Comment: You might be able to get it to simulate stably if you use a continuous input voltage. So, a piecewise-linear ramp instead of a step function.

Comment: When we use analysis (whatever), some resistors are automatically added (1 TOhm) at all points making the "matrix" singular. In your case, there is one resistor between the two capacitors and the ground. So, the lower capacitor wired to the ground has a voltage = 0. To see "something", you need (for example) to use a square wave generator (0-5 V). Then when the square wave goes 5 V, the center point goes 2.5V (checked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Circuits with capacitors and DC sources are problematic in SPICE because SPICE relies on currents (not only LTspice -- note the spelling). If the circuit is static (no dynamics involved) then the solver will try to find an operating point by opening up the capacitors and shorting out the inductors. In your case, the caps will be considered opened and the midpoint will show zero volts.

If you add a DC path to ground then the solver will find the operating point based off on those resistors. For example, if `C1` is 1 μF and `C2` is 2 μF, for a 1 V DC you'd expect the midpoint to be 0.333 V. But, if the resistors are both 1 GΩ then the voltage will read 0.5 V.

So you need to add some form of dynamics and that can be achieved in several ways:

- Add a ramp ([@Hearth's suggestion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/638588/ltspice-capacitor-only-circuit-dc#comment1692239_638588) in the comments), e.g. `PWL 0 0 1m 1` and simulate with `tran 1m`. Even with the two 1 GΩ resistors you will get the correct result: ⅓ of the voltage across the 2 μF. The downside is the ramp, itself. You could apply a derivative, but that comes with its own baggage, so it gets unnecessary complicated.
- Make the input source some sort of a step voltage. This can be achieved in several ways:

  1. Make the source, itself, `PWL 0 0 1u 1` (for example). For the aforementioned `.tran 1m`, this will make the source step from 0 to 1 V in 1 μs.
  2. Leave the source unchanged and add `startup` to the simulation command. This will add a fixed ramp of 20 μs to the DC supplies, the equivalent of `PWL 0 0 20u 1` here. Same as above, only larger ramp.
  3. Same unchanged source but with the `uic` flag. That causes the engine to start from zero and the very next simulation step will be full speed (or close, it's a bit complicated). That can be 1 million times less than the total simulation time, or even more (it depends on various factors). Suffice to say that the effect is starting from zero.

For points 1 and 2 the solver will still try to find the operating point but, since the supply is zero at t=0, the op. pnt. will be zero, too. The `uic` flag will force the solver to skip finding any operating points and start from zero, as if the Big Bang starts with your pressing the "run" button.

The downside for these last three points are the apparent stepped voltage. But, if the only thing of interest is seeing the DC parts then you can use the `.tran` command to save from after the transients. E.g. for `startup` you can set it to be `.tran 0 1m 20u`.