# Laplace transform for circuit analysis gives me different result from LTSpice Simulation

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform

Here is a simple circuit I want to simulate with LTSpice. I make everything to be 1 for easy arithmetic. The source is $$V_1 = cos(t) u(t)$$

[image]

$$H(s) = \frac{R} {R + \frac{1} {s C} + s L}$$

Substitute 1 for L, R and C.

$$H(s) = \frac{s} {s^2 + s +1}$$

The Laplace transform of the input is

$$V_1(s) = \frac{s} {s^2 + 1}$$

$$V_{R_1}(s) = \frac{s} {s^2 + 1} \times \frac{s} {s^2 + s +1}$$

The inverse Laplace transform of ( V_{R_1}(s) )

$$V_{R_1}(t) = \biggl(\frac{1} {\sqrt{3}} e^{-t/2} \sin{\frac{\sqrt{3}} {2} t}- e^{-t/2} \cos{\frac{\sqrt{3}} {2} t} + \cos{t} \biggl) u(t)$$

Here is the plot from Matlab
[image]

The other is the simulation from LTSpice.

[image]

**Where am I misunderstanding?**

Comment: Did you tell LTSpice to not evaluate the operating point?

Comment: @Andyaka What is operating point? Could you specify it a little bit?

Comment: See my answer please.

Comment: @kile You will have to make a tiny little effort and understand the tool you're using before pointing the finger. The explanations in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/638614/95619) apply to your case, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you call it in LTSpice but, in microcap, it's called the operating point and, if I plot your response allowing microcap to evaluate the operating point it comes up with exactly what your LTSpice shows. If I tell microcap not to calculate the operating point I get the MATLAB response: -

[image]

With microcap choosing the operating point: -

[image]

It's a common enough problem. Simulators try to do everyone a favour by calculating the steady-state DC conditions before doing an analysis but, if you are looking for true "do it from zero time" response, you need to deselect that dubious "feature".

If you set inductor current initial conditions to zero amps using `.IC i(L1) = 0` then this is the same as turning off the automatic operating point "feature".

Comment: This is AC because of $$\cos(t) u(t)$$. How can it have steady-state DC conditions?
Can you explain it a little bit?

Comment: I'm just the messenger telling you how to fix things @kile. We know it can't have DC conditions but a simulator has no idea and goes ahead and tries to calculate them based on the time you set to do the complete transient analysis.